# require/include throwing warning: no such file or directory in

Tags: php, include, require, require-once, include-once

I'm getting a rather frustrating warning which is blocking me from further development.

I've tried using `require_once` / `include_once` for a file with a relative path, and it seems to be unable to find it. Then all of a sudden it works, and now it doesn't work.

What could be causing this problem?

**Detailed screenshot of my file and paths:**

[image]

Notice that line 3 works, but line 4 doesn't work.

**Warning I'm getting client side:**

[image: warning require/include file or directory not found]

Thanks.

**Update with a screenshot of my finder:**

[image]

Comment: Triple check that your IDE is not deceiving you with some out-of-date file listing which doesn't actually exist on disk.

Comment: @deceze thanks for the comment and I checked. I added a screenshot of what my finder shows.

Comment: @Grimbode what permissions have `specialitieslist.php`?

Comment: @Leggendario "**-rwxr-xr-x+**" and I'm admin.

Comment: Have you tried to delete it manually from server and re-create it ?
Is the problem showing at every run or is it random ?

Comment: No and it's showing at every run. I'll try recreating it in a sec.